# How to inject Javascript in html template (html/template) with Golang?

Tags: go, go-html-template

Is there any way to inject Javascript as a variable in Golang html template (`html/template`). I was expecting the script to be injected in the template however script is injected as string inside `"`.

template.html

```
...
<head>
    {{ .myScript }}
</head>
...
```

parser.go

```
    ...
    fp := path.Join("dir", "shop_template.html")
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(fp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    return tmpl.Execute(writer, myObject{Script: "<script>console.log('Hello World!');</script>"})
    ...
```

rendered html output:

```
...
<head>
    "<script>console.log('Hello World!');</script>"
</head>
...
```

Expected output

```
<head>
    <script>console.log('Hello World!');</script>
   // And should log Hello World! in the console.
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the html/template package, this is the expected behavior. Regular strings should not be able to inject HTML/JS code.

If you trust the content, you can use `template.JS` or `template.HTML` types to inject JS and HTML code.

```
return tmpl.Execute(writer, myObject{
  Script: template.HTML("<script>console.log('Hello World!');</script>")})
```

Of course, you'll need to declare:

```
type myObject struct {
   Script template.HTML
   ...
}
```

instead of `string`.